# Scan accumulo using rowid

Tags: java, accumulo

How do I use the Java API to scan *accumulo* using only the rowid.  For example *accumulo* has the following row entry when I scan the table using the *accumulo* shell:

```
12lj314t1u43td1 Documents:Entity [U] {values}
```

I know the rowid in Java which is '12lj314t1u43td1'.  I want to retrieve `{values}` for all possible column families and qualifiers.  I already checked the *accumulo* documentation on scanner's but they do not say how to set the Ranges to only return based on the rowid.

Answer (score 4):

If there is just one rowID that you are interested in, than you can use the Scanner to accomplish this:

```
Scanner scanner = connector.createScanner(myTable, new Authorizations("U"));
scanner.setRange(new Range("12lj314t1u43td1"));

for(Entry<Key,Value> entry : scanner){
    System.out.println(entry);
}
```

This will give you every "12lj314t1u43td1" row.  If you only wanted the rows with the Documents cf, you'd add this after the `setRange` line

```
scanner.fetchColumnFamily(new Text("Documents"));
```

or if you wanted just the Documents with the Entity CQ you'd do

```
scanner.fetchColumn(new Text("Documents"), new Text("Entity"));
```

If you are looking for lots of discontiguous rows, then you might want to try the `BatchScanner`.   It is also possible to use a myriad of iterators and regex's, but this should get you what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can scan over a range in the shell with `scan -b startRow -e endRow`. See `scan --help` for more options.

Note: you should use the Java API if you want performance, but this gets you a range for the shell.